# WaitOne для объекта AutoResetEvent из разных потоков

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Ситуация следующая:
Есть класс:

```
public class Person
{
    private readonly AutoResetEvent _autoEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    public void Eat()
    {
        _taskFactory.StartNew(StartEat);
        autoEvent.WaitOne()
    }

    private void StartEat()
    {
        //Какие-то действия на протяжении 10 секунд минимум
        autoEvent.Set();
    }  
}

public class Manager
{
    public void Manage()
    {
        person.Eat();
    }
}
```

Есть 2 менеджера(Manager) и оба имеют ссылку на одного и того же Person(person). Как сделать так, чтобы при одновременной команде начать есть (eat) персоне оба менеджера ждали, пока он поест и вернет управление. Оба менеджера живут в своих потоках. 
Сейчас получается так, что каждый из менеджеров сделает собственный WaitOne, а вот  autoEvent.Set() будет лишь один раз для того потока, который первый дал команду есть. Можно ли обойтись без события?

Comment: Про флаг, что персона уже ест - понятно, не внес просто. Но проблема все равно та же, с WaitOne() из разных потоков. То есть второй менеджер должен дождаться, чтобы персона доела и после этого только управление можно ему вернуть

Comment: А чем обычный lock не подходит ? Залочили объект остальные потоки будут ждать.

Comment: а что лочить-то? все в методе Eat ? Второй поток потом заставит персону есть заново, а он должен просто дождаться, пока она доест в этот раз

Comment: А что означает «оба менеджера ждали, пока он поест»? А как они узнают, что он начал есть? Приведите желаемый порядок вызовов.

Comment: Да, и что должен делать менеджер в момент, когда Person не ест?

Comment: Первый менеджер вызвал метод Eat(). Не менее 10 секунд Person будет есть. Если в этот момент другой менеджер вызовет Eat(), он узнает по флагу, что  Person ест и должен будет "подключиться" к ожиданию того, пока Person поест. И вот как он поест, оба менеджера вернут себе управление

Comment: Когда Pesron не ест ничего делать не надо

Comment: А если Person поест до того, как второй менеджер вызовет Eat, он должен снова начать есть?

Comment: Да, он снова будет есть

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте, например, так:

```
object mutex = new object();
bool isRunning = false;
// AutoResetEvent не нужен
public void Eat()
{
    lock (mutex)
    {
        if (isRunning) // уже ест
        {
            // защита от spurious wakeup по идее не нужна
            Monitor.Wait(mutex); // надо дождаться конца
            return;              // и выйти
        }
        isRunning = true; // иначе начинаем есть
    } // отпускаем блокировку, она тут не нужна

    //Какие-то действия на протяжении 10 секунд минимум

    lock (mutex) // устанавливаем флаг, что мы не едим
    {
        isRunning = false;
        Monitor.PulseAll(mutex); // рассылаем сигнал всем интересующимся
    }
}
```

---

Как верно подсказывает @Pavel Mayorov, в случае если у вас возможны исключения в процессе работы, имеет смысл выполнить разблокировку внутри `finally`:

```
try
{
    //Какие-то действия на протяжении 10 секунд минимум
}
finally
{
    // даже если выполнение завершилось с исключением, мы выполним этот кусок
    lock (mutex) // устанавливаем флаг, что мы не едим
    {
        isRunning = false;
        Monitor.PulseAll(mutex); // рассылаем сигнал всем интересующимся
    }
}
```

Comment: А не проще ввести переменную состояния и проверять ее, например Interlocked -ом ?

Comment: @Luchunpen: Под `lock`'ом у меня есть гарантия, что пока я держу `lock`, никто не поменяет переменную. Представьте себе, что поток №1 проверил, увидел false. Контекст ушёл в поток №2, он проверил и увидел false. Теперь оба начинают длинные действия одновременно. Упс.

Comment: @Luchunpen: А если вы будете через `Interlocked.Exchange`, всё равно нужно как-то дождаться пробега другого потока. Это или `Monitor`, или снова `AutoResetEvent`. Если `AutoResetEvent`, где гарантия, что event не выстрелит между моей проверкой и началом ожидания? С `lock`'ом гарантия есть. А если `Monitor`, то для него снова нужен `mutex`.

Comment: @VladD Второй `lock` должен быть в блоке `finally` - иначе при первой же ошибке все зависнет...

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Ну да, или глотать все исключения в полезной нагрузке.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за помощь!  А  lock (mutex) и внутри  Monitor.Wait(mutex); ни к чему страшному не приводит? Очень сложно осознать, что в действительности происходит

Comment: @Sleeeper: На время выполнения `Monitor.Wait` `lock` автоматически отпускается. // Пожалуйста!

Comment: а можно ли сделать так: Вместо   //Какие-то действия на протяжении 10 секунд минимум  использовать AutoResetEvent для своих целей внутри вашего решения. Фактически эти 10 секунд значат отправку сетевого запроса и получение ответа. Я тут бы хотел отправить запрос, повиснуть в WaitOne и по получении ответа сделать Set. Это и есть те 10 секунд(ну оочень приблизительно). Не поломается ли схема в этом случае? Премного благодарен

Comment: @Sleeeper: Да, дожно работать по идее.

Answer (score 2):

Ради полноты картины приведу решение на задачах:

```
private volatile Task eatTask;
public void Eat() {
  var localTask = eatTask;
  if (localTask != null) {
    localTask.Wait();
    return;
  }

  var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
  localTask = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref eatTask, tcs.Task, null);
  if (localTask != null) {
    localTask.Wait();
    return;
  }

  try {
    EatImpl();
    tcs.SetResult(null);
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    tcs.SetException(ex);
    throw;
  } finally {
    Debug.Assert(eatTask == tcs.Task);
    eatTask = null;
  }
}

private void EatImpl() {
  //Какие-то действия на протяжении 10 секунд минимум
}
```

Сразу предупреждаю - особых достоинств у этого решения нет. Единственное отличие - тот факт, что если возникло исключение, то оно будет распространено на ожидающие потоки. Но того же эффекта можно добиться проще.

Comment: Вот ещё по теме, кстати: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/12/10266988.aspx

Comment: Огромное спасибо! На осознание также нужно время. как и в предыдущем ответе.